# Why Hybrid android application getting popular than native?

Tags: java, android, cordova, ionic-framework

I  want to know why hybrid applications are getting popular than native android applications?

And I have one more doubt,
Is hybrid applications can do all actions like native application?

Comment: Not a question for SO.

Comment: @Manu my doubt is... Is hybrid application is equal to native application??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hybrid apps are hyped because you don't have to do double (or more) the amount of work for several platforms. 
One page, web-based, deployable on multiple systems without much effort.

By now, hybrid apps can pretty much call everything native they want, PhoneGap made quite an impact with their JavaScript hooks for interaction with native functions.

Nevertheless, I'm actually quite against that hybrid hype, I don't like the Look'n'Feel of web-based apps, neither do I think the lazy way is the best way. 
I rather code natively and make use of everything powerful and useful the manufacturer created for me, to make really optimized, high quality apps.

But I guess, everyone's entitled to their own opinion.

Comment: A native app does not equal an optimized, high quality app by default. Neither does a hybrid app by default mean its a non-optimized, low quality app...

Comment: No one said that. But a hybrid, web-based app will never have the look'n'feel of a native app, nor the snappy reaction to any input or complex graphics.

Answer (score 0):

Write once, run anywhere :-) And you can publish new functions or fix bugs at any time. But there are serval problems with webview on android.

First, the WebView need too much memory, and may lead OOM, so you have to run it in an isolated process.

Second, the webview can not always run consistently in different ROMs, so you have 
test it with many devices before it published.

The Third, WebView does too much work on main thread, so it can not support complex animation.

May be you will interesting with React Native :-)

Comment: yes,But without internet hybrid applications cannot work right???

Comment: **wrong** of course they can work!

Comment: @Sithys how buddy??? we can store upto 5 mb only na... So how it acts like native app???

Comment: Well, they **can** work, it's just not fun to make them work offline (lot's of storing, fallbacks, pre-preparations), where native applications don't have these problems (in that amount).

Comment: Where can you store "just" 5Mb? In the local storage, yes. But where do you need 5Mb of plain text? I never had this case. All of my hybrid applications (8) are working fine offline without any problems. Yes you have to build in fallbacks which gets triggerd if the app is on- or offline but if you've done a bunch of apps you've your library with snippets and its just copy and paste. I wrote a pendant to the WebSQL DB for the local storage. Its much more faster and doesn't need server communication. Biggest library i ever wrote, but if you've done the work once, you'll never have to do it again

Comment: Imho, I rather code clean and native, than having the hassle of building all the web fallbacks, trying to mind every single pitfall out there that comes with web-technology and multiplatform-problems (with little to no chance of success of nailing it in the first few weeks). Just my 2c.

Comment: Using PhoneGap / Cordova you don't have to be limited to 5Mb storage and have other storage options.  I have an app in the App Store and Google Play using Cordova that makes use of a >100Mb encrypted SQLite database via a Cordova plugin.